# Hibernate query wrong entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Sorry if duplicate, really tried to get an answer to this but couldn't solve.

I have a superclass for all my entitys:

```
public abstract class ZafiroEntity implements Serializable, Cloneable{
    private String codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private Long id;
    private boolean habilitado;
    private Date lastSessionActivity;
...getters()
...setters()
}
```

Then I have hibernate xmls like this:

```
<class name="com.ansal.entities.Articulo" table="articulos">  
        <id name="codigo" type="string" column="codigo"></id>
        <property name="nombre" type="string" column="nombre"></property>
        <property name="descripcion" type="string" column="descripcion"></property>
        <property name="lista1" type="string" column="lista1"></property>
        <property name="lista2" type="string" column="lista2"></property>
        <property name="lista3" type="string" column="lista3"></property>
        <property name="lista4" type="string" column="lista4"></property>
        <property name="lista5" type="string" column="lista5"></property>
        <property name="oferta" type="boolean" column="oferta"></property>
        <property name="unidad" type="string" column="unidad"></property>
        <property name="totalVentas" type="long" column="total_ventas"></property>
        <property name="fechaCreacion" type="timestamp" column="fecha_creacion"></property>
        <property name="reemplazaImagenImportador" type="boolean" column="reemplaza_imagen_importador"></property>
        <property name="reemplazaDocumentoImportador" type="boolean" column="reemplaza_documento_importador"></property>
        
        <set name="listas" table="articulo_lista" inverse="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" lazy="false">
            <key column="articulo_codigo"/>
            <many-to-many class="com.ansal.entities.Lista">
                <column name="grupo_codigo" />
                <column name="subgrupo_codigo" />
                <column name="lista_codigo" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        
        <list name="atributos" table="articulo_atributos" lazy="false" inverse="false" cascade="all" fetch="select">
            <key column="articulo_codigo"/>
            <index column="orden"/>
            <many-to-many column="idatributo" class="com.ansal.entities.Atributo"/>
        </list>
        
        <list name="imagenes" table="articulo_imagenes" lazy="false" inverse="false" cascade="all" fetch="select">
            <key column="articulo_codigo"/>
            <index column="orden"/>
            <many-to-many column="idfile" class="com.ansal.entities.ZFile"/>
        </list>
        
        <list name="documentos" table="articulo_documentos" lazy="false" cascade="all" inverse="false" fetch="select">
            <key column="articulo_codigo"/>
            <index column="orden"/>
            <many-to-many column="idfile" class="com.ansal.entities.ZFile"/>
        </list>
    </class>
    
    <class name="com.ansal.entities.ArticuloCI" table="articulos">  
        <id name="codigo" type="string" column="codigo"></id>
        <property name="nombre" type="string" column="nombre"></property>
        <property name="lista1" type="string" column="lista1"></property>
        <property name="lista2" type="string" column="lista2"></property>
        <property name="lista3" type="string" column="lista3"></property>
        <property name="lista4" type="string" column="lista4"></property>
        <property name="lista5" type="string" column="lista5"></property>
        <property name="oferta" type="boolean" column="oferta"></property>
        <property name="unidad" type="string" column="unidad"></property>
    </class>

    <class name="com.ansal.entities.CommerceItem" table="commerce_item">  
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id"  unique="true"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="articulo" class="com.ansal.entities.ArticuloCI" lazy="false">
            <column name="codigo_articulo" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="cantidad" type="int" column="cantidad"></property>
        <property name="precioVenta" type="string" column="precio_venta"></property>
        <property name="precioTotal" type="string" column="precio_total"></property>
        <property name="cantidadConfirmada" type="int" column="cantidad_confirmada"></property>
        <set name="reemplazos" table="commerce_item_reemplazo" cascade="save-update" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key column="id_ci_padre"/>
            <many-to-many class="com.ansal.entities.CommerceItem">
                <column name="id_ci_reemplazo" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
```

But when I try to filter:

```
String query = "from com.ansal.entities.Articulo a WHERE (a.descripcion is null OR a.descripcion = '')";
List<Articulo> articulos = (List<Articulo>) HibernateUtils.get(query, new HashMap<>(), Articulo.class);


public static <T> List<T> get(String query, Map<String,Object> params, Class<T> t) throws Exception {
        return get(query, params, t, 0, 0);
    }

public static <T> List<T> get(String query, Map<String,Object> params, Class<T> t, int maxItems, int firstRow) throws Exception {
        SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Exception ex = null;
        List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Query q = session.createQuery(query,t);
            for(String key: params.keySet()){
                if(isDate(params.get(key))){
                    q.setParameter(key, params.get(key), TemporalType.DATE);
                } else {
                    q.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
                }
            }
            if(maxItems>0){
                q.setMaxResults(maxItems);
            }
            q.setFirstResult(firstRow);
            ret = q.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ex = e;
            Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Then it returns an Exception stating it doesn't have the property "descripcion", and after debugging I found that the query is building as "from com.ansal.entities.ArticuloCI a WHERE (a.descripcion is null OR a.descripcion = '')".

I guess it may be connected by the inheritance.
Articulo extends ZafiroEntity and
ArticuloCI extends Articulo

More info: This a service only server, and since it has to return data and not proxys I tried to built multiple entities reflecting the data needed for each response/necessity.
Saves and updates works just fine.

Thanks in advance

Tried to google the problem, but I guess I'm missing the keywords to find a similar case or example.
Also checked the suggestion stackoverflow showed me before posting.
Sorry all.

Edit 1:ArticuloCI was me being lazy but it worked

```
public class Articulo extends ZafiroEntity {
    private String descripcion;
    private String lista1,lista2,lista3,lista4,lista5;
    private boolean oferta;
    private List<ZFile> documentos = new ArrayList<>();
    private String unidad;
    private List<ZFile> imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Date fechaCreacion = new Date();
    private Set<Lista> listas = new HashSet<Lista>();
    private Long totalVentas;
    private Set<Inventory> stock;
    private List<Atributo> atributos = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean reemplazaImagenImportador = true;
    private boolean reemplazaDocumentoImportador = true;
    //getters and setters
}

public class ArticuloCI extends Articulo{}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Currently the related entity `Articulo` is missing from the question.

Comment: What is the class Articulo and ArticuloCI looks like? Have you check [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) ?

Comment: there, I added the definitions, sorry for the late edit, had some days off with sickness